# Missing IPN Notification

Tags: paypal

I've been running a 'Buy Now' button on my website for several months now, and a couple weeks back I observed a purchase that had went through where no IPN was sent to my website from PayPal. Later purchases that day succeeded.

**Observations**

- PayPal had sent me an email notification that the purchase was successful, it also recorded this transaction in my account's payment log. This is normal.
- The IPN History had no record of any IPN entries for that transaction; there is no record of PayPal attempting to contact my website to notify it of the IPN. This is not normal.
- I have not modified the 'Buy Now' whatsoever in the past six months, and there is only one 'Buy Now' button connected to PayPal. Furthermore, this was the only payment that day that had failed to show up in the IPN History.

I've read (I forget the article) that this isn't all that uncommon (happens a few times a year for popular sellers). I don't know, however, what the solution is. I contacted PayPal support a week ago, and they have not gotten back to me.

Answer (score 3):

I find that if the purchaser uses Credit Card option to pay, and they go through the payment page, the very last page has another button. Some purchasers don't click that very last button. The result is that the payment happens, but the IPN to your notify_url does not trigger.

This problem does not happen if the purchaser uses their paypal account to purchase.

I am looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IPN can be delayed for various reasons, but it will usually post at some point.

I know just last week (or maybe the week before) the IPN servers were down so there were literally millions of IPN's that were qued up in the system and took a long time for them to get all caught up.

Usually, though, IPN works great and is pretty much real-time.

Comment: I'm fine with a delay of a couple days, but two weeks? I don't accept "do nothing" as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be delayed that long.  Are you using your profile settings to enable IPN or are you using notify_url from your pay requests?  Have you double checked your IPN history and your web server logs to ensure the IPN's aren't actually being sent but failing for some reason?  I've got a bunch of IPN's hitting my sandbox account that seem to be working as expected so I think the delays are caught up at this point.